# Flash MP3 player loop from XML playlist

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3

I have an mp3 player based on the School of Flash code. When I click "next song" I need it to go to the next song, unless it's the last song in the playlist in which case it needs to go back to song number 1 in the playlist.

The following code doesn't seem to do the trick, any ideas where I am going wrong?

```
var songlist:XMLList;
var currentIndex:Number = 0;
```

and..

```
function nextSong(e:Event):void
{
 if (currentIndex < (songlist.length() - 1))
 {
  currentIndex++;
 }
 else
 {
  currentIndex = 0;
 }

 var nextReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest(songlist[1].url);
 var nextTitle:Sound = new Sound(nextReq);
 sc.stop();
 title_txt.text = songlist[1].title;
 artist_txt.text = songlist[1].artist;
 sc = nextTitle.play();
 songPlaying = true;
 currentSound = nextTitle;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't it be `songlist[currentIndex]` instead of `songlist[1]`?